# Php mathematical operator if else issue

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to generate a random number that will give one of the 4 sentences a chance to display, for instance if the number is less to 25 and eqaul to 25.

code:

```
<?php 
$a = mt_rand(1,100); 

echo $a

if ($a<="25")
  {
  echo "sentence 1";
  }
  elseif ($a>="25")
  {
  echo "sentence 2";
  }
  elseif ($a<="75")
  {
  echo "sentence 3";
  }
  elseif ($t>="75")
  {
  echo "sentence 4";
  }

?>
```

I dont see why this doesn't work, it just gives me a blank page.

Comment: because there is an error `echo $a` u forgot ;

Comment: This isn't going to generate an error but it is poor logic. Lets say $a = 25. In the code above your first two conditionals would be true. Same if $a = 75; the last 2 would be. For some reason you've replaced $a with $t at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make your example more simpler by storing all those sentences in an array and choosing them randomly....

#### Way1: Using shuffle()

```
<?php
$input = array("Sentence 1", "Sentence 2", "Sentence 3", "Sentence 4", "Sentence 5");
shuffle($input);
echo $input[0];
```

#### Way 2: Using array_rand()

```
<?php
$input = array("Sentence 1", "Sentence 2", "Sentence 3", "Sentence 4", "Sentence 5");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input);
echo $input[$rand_keys];
```

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon is missing in your echo statement.

```
echo $a;
```

and also you are using an undefined variable `$t` in

```
elseif ($t>="75")
```

replace it with `$a`.